# Linked server issue

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I made a linked server between two sql server instances.  The remote one I have very little control over.  When I try a query I get this:

> Cannot obtain the schema rowset "DBSCHEMA_TABLES_INFO" for OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "172.18.4.179\JOURNYX". The provider supports the interface, but returns a failure code when it is used.

Is there any good way around this without having to do admin-level actions on the remote system?

Comment: Please include the versions of SQL Server on each side, the version of SQLNCLI installed, and the security mechanism being used (e.g. what user is the linked server connecting as, and what rights does that user have on the other end).

Comment: There is a microsoft connect item for a similar issue [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/465959/unable-to-query-linked-sql-server-2000) with some workarounds

Comment: Here is a [kb article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/906954)

Comment: OK, thanks.  I was hoping there would be a solution that would not require acting on the remote database.